# Not authorized for query on Mongodb shard from Mongoose driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using **mongoDB 2.6.7** and **mongoose 3.8.23** driver for **node.js**.
Database is sharded in 2 shards (each is separate replica) and everything looks ok when I enter mongo shell on any of instance, replica, mongos, config servers etc.

After that I have added **admin** user and **user** (named *normaluser*) for specific database I am connecting. I have added them on **mongos** instance. Users are :

```
[
{
    "_id" : "admin.adminuser",
    "user" : "adminuser",
    "db" : "admin",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "dbAdminAnyDatabase",
            "db" : "admin"
        },
        {
            "role" : "readWriteAnyDatabase",
            "db" : "admin"
        },
        {
            "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
            "db" : "admin"
        },
        {
            "role" : "clusterAdmin",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

and

```
[
{
    "_id" : "mydb.normaluser",
    "user" : "normaluser",
    "db" : "mydb",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "readWrite",
            "db" : "mydb"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

From my node.js application I am connecting to mongos instances (I have 2 mongos instances) like this :

```
mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://mongos-ip-1:27018,mongos-ip-2:27018/mydb', {user : 'normaluser', password : 'some-password', mongos : true, server : {poolSize : 5, keepAlive : true}}
```

I am successfully connected to database but when I try to query **mydb.some-collection** from application I get this error :

```
 Possibly unhandled MongoError: not authorized for query on mydb.some-collection
```

When I go to mongo shell on some of mongos instance and login as **normaluser** I can query anything and it is ok.

Does anyone knows why I cannot make any query although I have readWrite role to user and specify user in connection url of mongoose? Maybe I am missing something with mongoose?

I have even tried to put **dbOwner** role to **normaluser** but nothing changed

Thanks,
Ivan

Comment: The code bits you've included look fine to me. Can you show us more code, maybe the code for the finds? Even better, can you write a minimal script that demonstrates connecting with the right credentials and then failing to auth for a find?

Comment: I had the same problem ( and came here looking for answers.)  We eventually discovered there was a piece of code that was trying to update the connection timeout, which requires admin access, yet it failed and gave "not authorized for query on mydb.mycollection."  Not sure if you are in the same boat, but I would look for code that's trying to do administrative tasks.

Comment: Did you try manually giving that collection permissions with `db.auth` ? If not open up mongo shell and try [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.auth/#db.auth)

Comment: Any solutions for this problem ? I'm facing the same one.

Comment: I also had the same problem. My friend asked me to upgrade mongoose to version 3.8.27. After upgrading it worked for me.

Comment: could you show the node code, when trying to connect  to MongoDB?

Comment: HI ivan_zd, if your normaluser is created in the mydb database (rather than the default admin database) then does your connection need to specify the authentication database in your connection options? e.g.             `auth: {authdb: 'mydb'}`

Answer (score 2):

Ivan, try this syntax:

```
mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://user:pass@localhost:port/db, ...', opts);
```